# Upload multiple files using AJAX and servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I've tried almost everything available on the internet but nothing seems to be working.

I have a HTML5 filereader code which will get me all the files read from client side directory `var f = $('#fileUpload')[0].files;` Next thing I want to upload all these files with an AJAX request to a JAVA servlet POST method. for that I tried below code-

```
var data = new FormData();
        $.each(f, function(key, value)
        {
            data.append(key, value);
        });
postFilesData(data);
//some code..
    function postFilesData(data)
    {
     $.ajax({
        url: 'serv2',
        type: 'POST',
        //enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        processData: false, 
        mimetyep: 'multipart/form-data',
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data', 
        success: function(data)
        {
            //success
        },
        error: function(textStatus)
        {
            console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
        }
        });
    }
```

servlet code doPOst method-

```
System.out.println("Hi what request:"+ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request));
        System.out.println("hi bro");
    //  awsUpload.uploadData(foldername);
        System.out.println("outside aws");

        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();


        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        String uuidValue = "";
        FileItem itemFile = null;

        try {
            // parses the request's content to extract file data
            List formItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator iter = formItems.iterator();

            // iterates over form's fields to get UUID Value
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
                if (item.isFormField()) {

                }
                // processes only fields that are not form fields
                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    itemFile = item;
                }
            }
        }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

        //System.out.println(path);
    //  response.sendRedirect(path+"/user"+"/home.html");
    //  System.out.println("done");

        if(itemFile==null)
        {
            System.out.println("File Empty Found");
        }
        System.out.println("The File Name is"+itemFile.getName());
}
```

HTML code:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

        <input type="file" class="input-file" name="file[]" id="fileUpload" 
        onchange="fileChanged();" multiple mozdirectory="" 
        webkitdirectory="" directory=""/> <br/>
```

it prints "File Empty Found" and crashes on below line with NullPointerException. I understand it's not getting any data. Could you please point out piece of code which is wrong or code missing which needs to be added.

Comment: There's a lot which could be more debugged and nailed down, yet you didn't tell any word/detail about it. Work on that first and reduce the question to that. For example, is it multipart content? Is the while loop entered? Is there really no exception? (your code has an empty catch block which ignores any exception and continues code as if nothing exeptional happened).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your response guys..!! 
To answer @BalusC's questions, Yes it is multipart upload. It enters in while loop but no data was transferred from ajax call and code just broke at line- `System.out.println("The File Name is"+itemFile.getName());` since there was no item to get FileName of. Only exceptions I got was on console "NullPointerException" and on UI-console(while debugging in JS) "500 internal server error"
I was able to fix the code and was able to transfer data through AJAX call to Servlet. Below is the code. pretty much changed/restructured code for AJAX call and servlet code--

AJAX request--

```
var fd = new FormData();    
    //fd.append( 'file', $('#fileUpload')[0].files);//.files[0]);

    $.each($('#fileUpload')[0].files, function(k, value)
            {
                fd.append(k, value);
            });

    $.ajax({
      url: 'serv2',
      data: fd,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data){
        alert(data);
      }
    });
```

Servlet code-doPost method--

```
if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            writer.println("Request does not contain upload data");
            writer.flush();
            return;
        }
        // configures upload settings
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        factory.setSizeThreshold(THRESHOLD_SIZE);

        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        //upload.setFileSizeMax(MAX_FILE_SIZE);
        //upload.setSizeMax(MAX_REQUEST_SIZE);

        String uuidValue = "";
        FileItem itemFile = null;

        try {
            // parses the request's content to extract file data
            List formItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator iter = formItems.iterator();

            // iterates over form's fields to get UUID Value
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
                if (item.isFormField()) {
                    if (item.getFieldName().equalsIgnoreCase(UUID_STRING)) {
                        uuidValue = item.getString();
                    }
                }
                // processes only fields that are not form fields
                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    itemFile = item;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("no of items: " + formItems.size());
            System.out.println("FILE NAME IS : "+itemFile.getName());
    }
}
```

I was able to print no of file objects passed from UI which were correct. Thank you for your time guys..!! :)